# Phonegap app - How does this approach sound

Tags: gwt, cordova

I have a neat GWT app running that I have been trying for a while to get working on Android.  Problem was my RPC calls were failing because of Same Origin Policy constraints.  I have spent some time trying to get this to work and then wondered to myself,  why not just have my Android startup Activity pull the Home.html page from my GAE server and then I have no worries about SOP.  Presto,  works as expected,  So my question is as my app requires an internet connection to work at all it is only the initial caching of the JS stuff when I start the app for the first time where the user might see a delay.  Other than that all my RPC calls request very small amounts of data.  Do you think this will fly? The way ~I see it is if the JS is wrapped in the APK then the download/install will take longer and if it is dynamically retrieved from my server the initial startup will take longer but APK download will be quicker.  Is this a vaild assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are working around an issue and this isn't actually the way that you wanted to design your application. Have you tried enabling CORS on your GAE server, and if so, what went wrong?